# Jquery keypress to validate email inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

What I'd like to accomplish is this:

If a user types in a valid email, display the (`.check`)'ok' sign. If not valid, display nothing(for the time being. I'll put something in later). 
I have 3 email fields. I'm trying to 'validate' for each one.

```
<form id="emailsForm" method="POST" action="/account/recommend/">
    <div class="prepend">
        <p><strong>Emails:</strong></p>
        <div>
            <span class="added"><p class="check">ok</p></span>
            <input type="email" id="email1" class="input-text" onblur="alert(/([A-Z0-9a-z_-][^@])+?@[^$#<>?]+?\.[\w]{2,4}/.test(this.value))">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="added"><p class="check">ok</p></span>
            <input type="email" id="email2" class="input-text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="added"><p class="check">ok</p></span>
            <input type="email" id="email3" class="input-text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$("form#emailsForm :input").each(function(){
    $('input').blur(function() {
        var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (testEmail.test(this.value)){
            $('input').siblings(".check").css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
        else {

        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RFcaN/23/  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to find the sibling of `this` input, so change your selector from `$('input')` to `$(this)`.

Secondly, `.check` is not a sibling of the input. It's a descendant of the sibling.

```
$(this).siblings(".added").find('.check').css('visibility', 'visible');
```